# Basic function with list

Tags: list, functional-programming, scheme

We have a `list A (1 2 3 4 5 2 2 3 3 3 4 6 7)` and we want to get this numbers which number of meets are < then them.

```
numbers | meets
      1 = 1
      2 < 3
      3 < 4
      5 > 1
      4 > 2
      6 > 1
      7 > 1

Example:
Input:
list (1 1 2 3 2 3 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5)
Output:
(1 3 4)
```

Comment: Is it homework? Pls add homework tag. Sorry, but i do not understand the question :(

Comment: Nope, I have to solve one similar problem on my test after 1h...
list ( 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 4 4 4 5)
1 meets 4 times
2 meets 3 times
4 meets 3 times
5 meets 1 times
so the list is 1 2

Comment: meets = how many times number 1 is contained in List A, same for 2, 4, 5

Comment: You mean the number of occurrences of a list item should be smaller than the numeric item itself?

Comment: That's right! I corrected it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution, I followed @lbruder comment, but it's not clear to me why 1 appears in your output since if you were checking for smaller and equal 2 should have appeared also

```
> (define (occurences lst)
    (cond ((null? lst) empty)
          ((< (length (filter (lambda (x) (if (= x (car lst)) x #f)) lst)) (car lst)) (cons (car lst) (occurences (filter (lambda (x) (if (not (= x (car lst))) x #f)) lst))))
          (else (occurences (filter (lambda (x) (if (not (= x (car lst))) x #f)) lst)))))
> (occurences '(1 2 3 2 3 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5))
(3 4)
```

- number 1 occurrence 1  -> false 1 !< 1
- number 2 occurrence 2  -> false 2 !< 2
- **number 3 occurrence 2  -> true  2 <  3**
- **number 4 occurrence 2  -> true  2 <  4**
- number 5 occurrence 6  -> false 6 !< 5

Hence `(3 4)`

By `!<` , I mean not smaller (greater or equal)